# get a touch event in android framework tier, how to change it to system event

Tags: android, events

When I get a touch event with its coordinate in android frameworks, 
I can use ioctl to send the user event to kernel, 
then let the driver convert it to system input event.( use: input_sync, input_report_key, input_report_abs etc.)

The problem is:

As i known, the android swipe events may like this:(swipe down)
{ type, code, value }

```
    {3,48,5}, {3,50,1}, {3,53,240}, {3,54,400},
    {1,330,1},

    {3,58,255}, {3,57,0},
    {0,2,0},{0,0,0},

    {3,48,0},{3,50,1},{3,53,240},{3,54,450},{3,58,255},{3,57,0},
    {0,2,0},{0,0,0},

    {3,0,0},{3,1,450},{3,57,15},
    {0,0,0},{1,330,0},

    {3,48,0},{3,50,1},{3,53,240},{3,54,450},{3,58,0},
    {0,2,0},{0,0,0}
```

type=0, represents sync

type=1, represents key

type=3, code=53,54, value represents coordinate

type=3, code=48,50,57,58, value represents touch tool propertys.

so, only type=3, code=53,54 or type=1 are the input parameters, others need to be inserted in the convertion of user event to system event.

Should I coding like this:

```
// in driver
if ( get an event )
{
    report touch tool event;    
    report the x,y/key event;   // from input params
    report the sync event;
}
```

or there is a better way?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found linux uinput interface, which can generate input events in user space more convenient.

http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput